# spring amqp message CorrelationIdString is null

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

code like below i send a message and set it messageid and CorrelationIdString

```
rabbitTemplate.send(RabbitMQConfig.EXCHANGE_NAME, "aaa.orange.bbb",new Message(messageBody, MessagePropertiesBuilder.newInstance().setCorrelationIdString(uuid3).
                        setMessageId(uuid3).setContentType("text/x-json").build()),
                new CorrelationData(uuid3)

                );
```

and the receiver code

```
public void processMessage (Message msg) throws Exception {
//        Thread.sleep(100000);
        System.out.println("Receiver1 got message" + msg);
```

and the log

```
Receiver1 got message(Body:'hello,world1 2' MessageProperties [headers={spring_listener_return_correlation=93fbcc71-b0eb-4d33-a187-d4b27122a663}, timestamp=null, messageId=5f779051-12c5-43f1-a589-6d14430d3a52, userId=null, receivedUserId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, correlationIdString=null, replyTo=null, contentType=text/x-json, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=first_exchange, receivedRoutingKey=aaa.orange.bbb, receivedDelay=null, deliveryTag=1, messageCount=0, consumerTag=amq.ctag-JbtjvUYYqlWOIsgKkOe-8A, consumerQueue=queue_a])
```

my question is why CorrelationIdString  is null is that a problem or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We migrated away from a `byte[]` for correlationId to `String` in 1.6 and 1.7 but we had to stick with `byte[]` by default for backwards compatibility; the migration is complete in 2.0 (currently 2.0.2) and `correlationIdString` is not longer a property.

I suggest moving to 2.0.

Alternatively, if you must use an older version, see [`CorrelationIdPolicy` here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.7.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#message-properties-converters) to switch from `byte[]` to `String` or `BOTH`.

Answer (score 0):

For me I was forced to override createContainerInstance method to change the policy on the listener side.

```
 final DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter messagePropertiesConverter = new DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter();
    messagePropertiesConverter.setCorrelationIdPolicy(DefaultMessagePropertiesConverter.CorrelationIdPolicy.STRING);

    return new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected SimpleMessageListenerContainer createContainerInstance() {
            final SimpleMessageListenerContainer result = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
            result.setMessagePropertiesConverter(messagePropertiesConverter);
            return result;
        }
    };
```